# PEAR Mail package and IDN domains

Tags: email, pear, idn

I'm using PEAR Mail package in many projects, sending mails via smtp method. But I found out there's a problem with IDN domains (like tüv.de). The PEAR package rejects mails containing german umlauts with "Validation failed for..."
So it seems, that the RFC822 validation function in this package doesn't work correctly? Is there a solution, so I don't have to adopt all projects using another package?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think with idn_to_ascii from idn package I can convert right part of mail address to rfc822 compliant domain name, so this question is solved.